# Delay API response and page blank

Tags: angular

My API returning data slow, it take several seconds. 
My page get loaded with blank, I can see api response on console after few second, but my page don't get data automatically. If I do inspect and close inspect window, I can see data on screen. I am not able to find out reason.

Is there a way, either delay the page load till API returns response or once component get response page will get data automatically.

Using angular 6

```
import { Observable, fromEventPattern } from 'rxjs';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
```

app.component.ts . Fetching response from API

```
getData(){
    this.http.get(URL)
     .subscribe((response) => {
      this.gdata = response;

    })
  }
```

app.component.html look like this.

```
<div  class="row" *ngFor="let data of (gdata | groupBy:'Sport' )">
```

not using service.ts .. below is full component

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, fromEventPattern } from 'rxjs';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';




@Component({
  selector: 'm-sport-profile',
  templateUrl: './sport-profile.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./sport-profile.component.scss']
})
export class sportProfileComponent implements OnInit {

  private Id : any;
  private gData = [];

  private URL = 'http://localhost:65210/api/sports/';  // URL to web api
  private URL2 : string;  

  constructor(    private http: HttpClient, private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

  ngOnInit() {

    this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
      this.Id = params['Id']; //get specific query param
  })

    this.URL2 = this.URL+this.Id;
    this.getsportDetail();

  }


  getsportDetail(){
    this.http.get(this.URL2)
      .subscribe((response) => {
      this.gData = response;      
    })
  }



}
```

below is PIPE

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
@Pipe({name: 'groupBy'})
export class GroupByPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(collection: Array<any>, property: string): Array<any> {
        if(!collection) {
            return null;
        }
        const groupedCollection = collection.reduce((previous, current)=> {
            if(!previous[current[property]]) {
                previous[current[property]] = [current];
            } else {
                previous[current[property]].push(current);
            }
            return previous;
        }, {});
        return Object.keys(groupedCollection).map(key => ({ key, value: groupedCollection[key] }));
      }

}
```

Comment: Are you getting any error

Comment: no error. I can see response on console. and if I open and close console.. data get reflect on page too.

Comment: just put `<pre>{{gdata | json}}</pre>` in html and check if you can see the response there.

Comment: not getting print, same result and behavior.

Comment: Share the more code from component and service.

Comment: @SunilSingh: Added.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182520/discussion-between-fresher-and-sunil-singh).

Answer (score 0):

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, fromEventPattern } from 'rxjs';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';




@Component({
selector: 'm-sport-profile',
templateUrl: './sport-profile.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./sport-profile.component.scss']
})
export class sportProfileComponent implements OnInit {

private Id: any;
private gData = [];

private URL = 'http://localhost:65210/api/sports/';  // URL to web api
private URL2: string;

constructor(private http: HttpClient, private route: ActivatedRoute) {
}

ngOnInit() {

    this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
        this.Id = params['Id']; //get specific query param
        this.URL2 = this.URL + this.Id;
        this.getsportDetail();
    })
}


getsportDetail() {
    this.http.get(this.URL2)
        .subscribe((response) => {
            this.gData = response;
        })
}



}
```

Hope this works. Because you can do the second function only when the first function gets the value and you use that in the second function.

One thing you can try is Use `ngOnChanges()`.

Please refer the [documentation](https://angular.io/api/core/OnChanges) for more details.

And there are plenty of questions already out there which explains dynamic loading. Please check them out.

Answer (score 0):

Try using something like

```
<div class="row" *ngFor="let data of ((gdata | async) | groupBy:'Sport')">
```

and see if that works for you. The async pipe is used to wait for content to be set from a promise or observable. I can see the GroupBy pipe probably causes a render block since it expects gdata to be set on ngViewInit. You could also try moving the subscription to the constructor i.e.

```
constructor(private http: HttpClient, private route: ActivatedRoute) {
   this.http.get(URL).subscribe((response) => {
      this.gdata = response;
   })  
}
```

To make sure the request is being queued as early as possible in the lifecycle. Let me know if it works.

Comment: ((gdata | async) .. stopping component.html, putting into constructor also not helping.

Comment: Can you publish your snippets on stackblitz so I can debug? @fresher, I tried setting it up but there's a lot missing